# Using OpenMP multithread is much slower than single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallel my C++ Neural Network Training Process using OpenMP. But it won't work.
And then I used a simple C++ code with nested loops to test the OpenMP.
But it is much slower with OpenMP multithread than single thread.
Did I do something wrong to make it slower? Or did I miss something?

#### System

MacOS 4 cores

#### Language

C++

#### Time functions

I used both **high_resolution_clock::now()** and **omp_get_wtime()**.

1. `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`

> single thread cost time: 0.00000000000000
> 2 threads cost time: 0.00010013580322
> 4 threads cost time: 0.00016403198242
> 6 threads cost time: 0.00017309188843
> 8 threads cost time: 0.00112605094910
> 10 threads cost time: 0.00013613700867
> 12 threads cost time: 0.00082898139954

2. `omp_get_wtime();`

> single thread cost time: 0.00000005900000
> 2 threads cost time: 0.00009907600000
> 4 threads cost time: 0.00018207300000
> 6 threads cost time: 0.00014479500000
> 8 threads cost time: 0.00070604400000
> 10 threads cost time: 0.00057277700000
> 12 threads cost time: 0.00074358000000

#### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void test() {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        // do something to kill time...
        j++;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // without openMp
    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    chrono::duration<double> diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << setprecision(14) << fixed;
    cout << "single thread cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    // 2 threads
    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "2 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    // 4 threads
    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "4 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    // 6 threads
    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "6 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(8)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "8 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(10)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "10 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(12)
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        test();
    }
    endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    diff = endTime - startTime;
    cout << "12 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;

    // system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

#### How I compile the code

> clang++ -std=c++11 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp parallel.cpp -O3 -o parallel -lomp

## Update

Hi guys, the previous problem has solved, I think I should not use NUM_THREAD.

But when I use OpenMP to accelerate my neural network, it takes longer time.

#### Data size

MNIST dataset, 60000 each epoch

#### Time Function

omp_get_wtime()

#### Single thread result

> ***** train epoch 1.
> Batch count: 6000.
> batch size: 10.
> Progress: 5999/6000.
> train time is ... 64.7082.
> Accuracy: 97.72% 9772/10000.
> predict time is ... 3.51836.
> Releasing Data Samples...
> Releasing Neural Network...

#### Result with OpenMP

> ***** train epoch 1.
> Batch count: 6000.
> batch size: 10.
> Progress: 5999/6000.
> train time is: 247.615.
> Accuracy: 97.72% 9772/10000.
> predict time is: 30.739.

#### Code using **parallel for**

```
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            layer->map[i].data[k] = activation_func::tan_h(layer->map_common[k] + layer->map[i].b);
            // cout << "current thread: " << omp_get_thread_num() << endl;
        }
```

#### Code using **parallel for** and **omp critical**

```
for (int k = 0; k < layer->map_count; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map_h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map_w; j++) {
                double max_value = prev_layer->map[k].data[2*i*upmap_w + 2*j];
                for (int n = 2*i; n < 2*(i + 1); n++) {
                    #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (int m = 2*j; m < 2*(j + 1); m++) {
                         #pragma omp critical
                        max_value = MAX(max_value, prev_layer->map[k].data[n*upmap_w + m]);
                    }
                }
                layer->map[k].data[i*map_w + j] = activation_func::tan_h(max_value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your test loop doesn't really do anything, so the compiler might be removing it. Then the time you get would be mostly the time spent creating threads.

Comment: The test function should return the value and your code should print it somewhere. AS @1201ProgramAlarm has said, the compiler might detect that you're just wasting compute time and remove the loop.

Comment: 9 women can't make a baby in a month! Your computation time is too small so that multithreading can be useful. Creating/Ending threads take time. Furthermore please use the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and not `num_threads(...)`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard about the last remark, not sure that in case it would work since OP has multiple parallel regions with different number of threads

Comment: @dreamcrash Yeah but I think this is better to move away the (copy-past-based) benchmarking code in a dedicated script (eg. bash). This is not critical anyway here since the program is a benchmark.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Now I understand what you mean, yep it would have been much better to have a single block of code and changing the number of threads from the outside

Comment: `layer->map[i].data[k] = ...` with `k` coming from different threads may be a performance suicide if it implies that you force different threads to access consecutive elements of an array/vector. The cache in your machine surely would not be  happy with this.  Also, critical section in a tight parallel loop is another performance killer. The loop seems to be embarrassingly parallel, so  getting rid of the critical section  appears quite possible and easy.

Comment: I would also move paralelization one loop embedding up, just below  `double max_value =`, to avoid frequent fork/join overhead. Also, store `max_value` local to each thread in an array local to the appropriate loop, then reduce these values and the   value from `double max_value =` to a single value that you use in `layer->map[k].data[i*map_w + j] =...`. This will enable you to get rid of the critical section. Use  the current thread number for the array index.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to parallel my C++ Neural Network Training Process using
> OpenMP. But it won't work. And then I used a simple C++ code with
> nested loops to test the OpenMP.

I see this quite often; **Introducing OpenMP in a code, or parallelism for that matter, will not magically make your code faster.**

Why ?? because of a lot of factors but (in your context) because the work done in parallel should be big enough to overcome the overhead of the parallelism (*e.g.,* thread creation, synchronization and so). To do that you need to increase the size/number of the parallel tasks.

Another issue is with the way you are benchmarking the code:

Your parallel task:

```
void test() {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        // do something to kill time...
        j++; <---- Not enough work done in parallel 
    }
};
```

In the sequential version the compiler can *easily* deduct that `j = 100000 - 1;`. Moreover, because you are not doing anything with that value (*i.e.,* `j`) the compiler can actually optimized the entire call to the `test()` function away. Hence, as pointed out in the comments:

> Your test loop doesn't really do anything, so the compiler might be
> removing it. **Then the time you get would be mostly the time spent
> creating threads.** – 1201ProgramAlarm

and

> The test function should return the value and your code should print
> it somewhere. **AS @1201ProgramAlarm has said, the compiler might detect
> that you're just wasting compute time and remove the loop.** – Michael
> Klemm

Furthermore, instead of having the following block of code:

```
// 2 threads
startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    test();
}
endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
diff = endTime - startTime;
cout << "2 threads cost time: " << diff.count() << endl;
```

replicated a bunch of times, it would have been better to have it a single time and change the number of threads using the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`  from the outside.

Regarding your update:

```
for (int k = 0; k < layer->map_count; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map_h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map_w; j++) {
                double max_value = prev_layer->map[k].data[2*i*upmap_w + 2*j];
                for (int n = 2*i; n < 2*(i + 1); n++) {
                    #pragma omp parallel for
                    for (int m = 2*j; m < 2*(j + 1); m++) {
                         #pragma omp critical
                        max_value = MAX(max_value, prev_layer->map[k].data[n*upmap_w + m]);
                    }
                }
                layer->map[k].data[i*map_w + j] = activation_func::tan_h(max_value);
            }
        }
    }
```

that `critical section` is basically making the code sequential. Actually even worse than sequential because there is the additional overhead of the locking mechanism.

Instead of `#pragma omp critical` you should use the OpenMP reduce, which is exactly meant for this kind of situations. Moreover, you can try to parallelize the `for (int n = 2*i; n < 2*(i + 1); n++)` instead:

```
for (int k = 0; k < layer->map_count; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < map_h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < map_w; j++) {
                double max_value = prev_layer->map[k].data[2*i*upmap_w + 2*j];
                #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max: max_value)
                for (int n = 2*i; n < 2*(i + 1); n++) {
                    for (int m = 2*j; m < 2*(j + 1); m++) {
                        max_value = MAX(max_value, prev_layer->map[k].data[n*upmap_w + m]);
                    }
                }
                layer->map[k].data[i*map_w + j] = activation_func::tan_h(max_value);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

1. A side note, personally, and don't take it in the wrong way, but I think you should spend more time learning first the basics of multithreading and OpenMP before trying to *blindly* parallelize code.
2. Please, don't keep adding updates to the original question, with newer question. Just create a new question instead.